# check from a class (javabean) if a session exist

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to check if a session exists. If exists i let the users see pages, otherwise i redirect him to the login page.

So i thought i need to call a class, at the beginning of every jsp page and every servlet, that checks the session.

Now i understood that i can do it just in a servlet. Since i cant call that servlet by writing `<jsp:usebean...`, I dont' know how to call it. I dont want that servlet writes my whole html page, i want it just tells me if a session exist.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali if you want a exact solution, please share your servlet class and jsp. Then explain what you want to do with them.